# CoreBluetooth: How to obtain Bluetooth MAC address of BLE device I'm connected to?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Is there a particular service and characteristic that I can read from a BLE device that will provide its MAC address?
I've tried reading the Serial Number in the blind hope that it was the MAC (from the Device Info), but attempting to do so seems to give an error.
I'm coding this for iOS, but if iOS is blocking my good-natured desire to obtain data, I'd be willing to dump it and move to Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get public Bluetooth Device Address using core\_bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078681/how-to-get-public-bluetooth-device-address-using-core-bluetooth)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BluetoothDevice.getAddress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getAddress()).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot obtain the device MAC address using Core Bluetooth on iOS.

Comment: Too bad. How long is the randomly-generated Apple UUID valid for typically?

Comment: It should be valid indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the BlE accessory,you can add a MAC address to your advertisementData,so that you can get the MAC address even without connectting.
But since you can always get your BlE accessory's UUID,why bother use MAC address instead.