# How to filter BLE devices before showing it to user?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am working on a BLE app which requires me to connect a BT device to an iPhone app.

I am able to scan all the devices and a user can connect it too. But the question is, how to filter the devices after scanning (and before showing it for connection), there can be number of BT devices (just in case), and a user may connect with other BT device from our app, however it will be non of the use but still for application integrity, I want to show only those devices which I want too. I know we can filter out devices by passing UUIDs, but wait, those devices can be any device around the world so I just can't fix it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Normally you would scan only for the devices that are advertising the service you are interested in and only display those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **"Proximity"** of BLE devices in order to get the range. I used the same scenario for my BLE devices. You can get the proximity of the BLE devices and let the user know which device is the closest.

By putting the device closer to your mobile (assuming app is made for mobile application). You can connect to the closest BLE device and configure it. Hope it helps.

Comment: that's fine, but how one can know that which device is the one which I need to connect? If I put three different kind of BT devices near the mobile then it will show me all the devices but I only want to show the devices which I requires.

Comment: @Hemang You can put an unique string or number in the `advertisementData`, thats what we did, optionally you can scan with services, then make some unique service UUID.

Comment: In general, you can show the most closest device on Top of the list in the application. You can mention it in your application this way, as a help:** _"Please move your BLE device closer to phone in order to configure it"_ **  OR assuming if you know the BLE devices you can mark them with some label on TOP like BLE ID: 1 with a sticker and in application you can show the device which do you want to configure based on proximities. So the user will know which device is going to be configured.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the devices with respect to the MAC address (it is part of  the parameter "BluetoothDevice" of the ScanResponse). This is useful if the MAC address contains an Organizationally Unique Identifier (OUI). See here: http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/tut/eui.pdf for more info.

Typically the first three bytes contain the OUI, thereby guaranteeing that you can easily filter out all devices belonging to an organization. So it would be preferrable if the first three bytes of all your BT devices are always fixed. In this case, you can filter for these bytes and see only your devices.

**Edit:** Since on iOS it is not possible to directly get the MAC address via ScanResponseData, you can modify the manufacturer specific part of the scan response, including the MAC-Address there.

Comment: In iOS you can't access the MAC address of the device. Only it's UUID, and it may change if you didn't pair with it.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, sorry. I overlooked that it was iOS. But don't you get the device name to filter for? Alternatively, you can explicitly include the MAC address in the scan response data.

Comment: You can get the name, but their may be duplicates. Only the UUID should be used to differentiate them.

Comment: Well if you MUST use the UUID, then your chances are very bad, since you can't predict how a UUID will look like in advance. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078681/how-to-get-public-bluetooth-device-address-using-core-bluetooth. Under that premise, I doubt that there is a way to realize it.